# iPhone - "Open In" in SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, dropbox, open-with

The DropBox app lets you view a document in another app by selecting the `Open In` option.

We are building a document management app and need to be able to view the Word/Excel docs like Dropbox does, in another app.

Where in the SDK do I look so that I can pass a document to another app to open in that one?

Ian

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to use the [`UIDocumentInteractionController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

It's available in UIKit, so you don't need a particular framework for this.

You instantiate this class, using an URL to the file you want to pass to another application, which is able to handle the file type:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController * controller;

controller = [ UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: someFileURL ];
```

Then, you can present it:

```
[ controller presentOpenInMenuFromRect: someRect inView: someView animated: YES ];
```

Note that, on iPad, you'll need to retain the controller, otherwise it will be deallocated, making your application crash.

This method returns a `BOOL` value. `NO` is returned if no application for the file type
was found. In such a case, you may display an alert.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the tip about retaining the UIDocumentInteractionController. Was driving me nuts. Also worth noting, I could never get it to work in the simulator. Only on devices.