# Opening installed application from another iOS application

Tags: ios, appdelegate

I trying to find a way for opening an installed application from my iPhone app with a selected image file. An app named "Good Reader" which i want to open from my app. Can anyone suggest the procedure.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can open URL from your app. I've found that Good Reader app has scheme [Goodreader:](http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/goodreader).

Comment: I haven't found it. But there is also another way to do it if app can open some documents' type. Look here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8302593/iphone-open-in-in-sdk

Comment: You can also ask developer. I think he'll answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can only launch apps that have registered a `URL scheme`. Then just like you open the SMS app by using `sms:`, you'll be able to open the app using their URL scheme..

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"Goodreader://"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:myURL];
```

check out This tutorial [Custom URL Scheme](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

Comment: Thanks for the URL. I am looking forward to open an image from my app to good reader. Can you suggest?